# How can I connect to a SQL Server Express database on my local machine from Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm running Visual Studio 2022, and I have a SQL Server Express database on the same machine that I want to access from Visual Studio.

Does anyone know how I can connect to it?

In Server Explorer, my machine is listed under "Servers", and under its "Services", "SQL Server (SCDO-Helper)", "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)", "SQL Server Agent (SCDO)", and "SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)" are all listed (see screenshot), but no amount of clicking, double-clicking, or right-clicking on any of them seems to do anything, other than bring up a context menu with "Refresh" and "Properties", neither of which do anything helpful.

I'm looking to have my database with its tables, definitions, etc. listed in the Server Explorer.

Comment: Generally I always use the *SQL Server Object Explorer*, rather than the *Server Explorer*, for your SQL Server connections. However, I think to see your sql server under the Server Explorer, you'd have to add a new connection.

Comment: You can't right-click "Data Connections" and add a connection?

Comment: @NickAbbot, yes, Thanks!  I was just confused because I could see my server there, and didn't realize I needed to add a connection